# How to upload a draft application using the new Android Developer Console?

Tags: android, apk, in-app-billing

Android requires you to upload an APK with billing permissions through developer console to start testing real in app billing. This was straingtforward in the old developer console but in the new one, as soon as you upload an APK, it activates automatically and there is no way to de-activate.

I've seen a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902554/android-publishing-draft-apks-and-in-app-billing-testing-how/13902919#13902919) where they suggest using the old developer console but developer console does not let me use the old console because our app listing has localized content.

**Update** To be more clear, it lets me switch back to the old console but there is a message near my app saying

> This app has localized images and/or videos, please edit in the new Developer Console.

instead of an edit button.

I've seen [other people](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg226381.html) having the same issue without a solution.

Any workaround to be able to upload draft apk through the new developer console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Google. Looks like at this state there is nothing to do. Even if I delete localized store content, it wont let me use old console. 
They said draft apk support is coming **very soon**.

Comment: looks like they just released it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. It seems the 'one click publish' is being advertised as a feature. They might eventually add some sort of draft support, but who knows.

Comment: BTW, it does go in a draft state before you publish it, so you test IAB. Once you publish though, there is no draft state for new version draft APKs.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it's available the option to deactivate a current published APK. At least, I was able to do it with the new Google Developer Console, one week ago.

Comment: yep, they fixed it 1 week after i created this question

Answer (score 0):

The old developer console is accessible by either going to the top right or navigating to play.google.com/apps/publish?switch_back=1

Comment: i can switch back but cannot edit the app. Updated the question to be more clear.